# Псевдо числа или как найти рандомное число

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть задача: найти число которое не будет совпадать с прошедшим найденным числом. Про Random.Range я знаю, но вот задачу выполнить не позволяют знания по математики.

Comment: т е нужен массив рандомных не повторяющихся чисел?

Comment: прошу простить, совсем забыл про вопрос. Именно так.

Answer (score 2):

```
        int Rand;
        int Lenght = 6;

        //список наших рандомных чисел
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        void Start ()
        {
            list = new List<int>(new int[Lenght]);

           //в цикле ищем наши числа
            for (int j = 0; j < Lenght; j++)
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1,6);

     //проверка существование числа в списке
                while (list.Contains(Rand))
                {
                    Rand = Random.Range(1,6);
                }

                list[j] = Rand;
                print(list[j]);
            }

        }
```